# Convert a dynamic piechart from CanvasJS to Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, canvasjs

I have a functional prototype of a medical app in which the user enters some numerical data in a form and upon clicking the submit button the data is analyzed via minimal euclidean distance and the results displayed as a pie chart in CanvasJS. The problem is I do not want CanvasJS, I prefer Google Charts or ChartJS (better looking), but I do not know how to convert the script displaying the result in CanvasJS to Google Charts for instance.

Here are the events triggered by clicking the Submit button:

```
<a href="formularResults.html"><input type="submit" value="Evaluează" onclick="algDiabet()"/></a>
```

Function algDiabet() computes the euclidean distance and returns the results as:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("LADA_Result", 0);
sessionStorage.setItem("SAID_Result", said_final);
sessionStorage.setItem("SIDD_Result", sidd_final);
sessionStorage.setItem("SIRD_Result", sird_final);
sessionStorage.setItem("MOD_Result", mod_final);
sessionStorage.setItem("MARD_Result", mard_final);
```

The script in formularResults.html which displays the computation results in CanvasJS is the following (is working fine):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Diabestes Type</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "formRez.css">
   
<script>

window.onload = function chart() {
    var LADA_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("LADA_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
    var SAID_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SAID_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
    var SIDD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SIDD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
    var SIRD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SIRD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
    var MOD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("MOD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
    var MARD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("MARD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );

    if(LADA_result == 0 && SAID_result != 100){
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            // theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
            backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
            exportEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Your diabetes type"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "pie",
                startAngle: 25,
                toolTipContent: "<b>{label}</b>: {y}%",
                showInLegend: "true",
                legendText: "{label}",
                indexLabelFontSize: 16,
                indexLabel: "{label} - {y}%",
                dataPoints: [
                    { y: SAID_result, label: "SAID" },
                    { y: SIDD_result, label: "SIDD" },
                    { y: SIRD_result, label: "SIRD" },
                    { y: MOD_result, label: "MOD" },
                    { y: MARD_result, label: "MARD" },
                ]
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    }

    else{
        if (SAID_result == 100) {
            document.location.href = "SAID.html";
        } 
        else {
            document.location.href = "LADA.html";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to display an identical pie chart in Google Charts, with the same labels "SAID", "SIDD", "SIRD", "MOD", "MARD" and the results of SAID_result, SIDD_result,  SIRD_result,  MOD_result, and  MARD_result but I do not know how to do it. Thank you for your help, Felix.

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple, just follow their example, [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#example)

by default, the google load statement will wait for the page to load
so you can use the promise returned by `google.charts.load` in place of `window.onload`

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var LADA_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("LADA_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
  var SAID_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SAID_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
  var SIDD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SIDD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
  var SIRD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("SIRD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
  var MOD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("MOD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );
  var MARD_result = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("MARD_Result")).toFixed( 2 );

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Category', 'Value'],
    ['LADA', LADA_result],
    ['SAID', SAID_result],
    ['SIDD', SIDD_result],
    ['SIRD', SIRD_result],
    ['MOD', MOD_result],
    ['MARD', MARD_result]
   ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat for your input, it is not working by I study the issue and will figure it out eventually!